# How do I check the contents of a String Builder

Tags: java, android

I am trying to parse some JSON and send it to a EditText field in my android application. I recently discovered that an error I was getting was stemming from the contents of my StringBuilder. Instead of using my StringBuilder I hardcoded a sample of json into a string and sent that to the EditText field. That works fine and I get the value I am looking for to show up. However I need this to work via accessing the API I am using and not hardcoding. Below is my JSON Parser class. Is there a way I can check what is in my stringBuilder after the append before inputStream is closed. This way I can sort that out and return my jSon back to stringBuilder.toString() instead of hardcoding it.

```
package com.apitest.rottentomatoestest;

import java.io.*;
import org.apache.http.*;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.*;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

static InputStream inputStream = null;
static JSONObject jObject = null;
static String jSon = "";

public JSONParser() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url){

    //Make HTTP Request
    try {
        //defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        inputStream = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");
        }
        inputStream.close();

        jSon = "{\"cast\":[{\"id\":\"162661723\",\"name\":\"Snoop Dogg\"}]}";

    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
    //try to parse the string to JSON Object
    try {
        jObject = new JSONObject(jSon);

    } catch (JSONException e){
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
    //return JSON String
    return jObject;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
Log.d("JSON Contents", stringBuilder.toString());
```

just before you close the inputStream.

Update: The `596 Service Not Found` message is often caused by an [incorrect URL](https://developer.bodymedia.com/forum/read/122978).

Comment: Thanks that did it. I see the contents of stringBuilder is <h1>596 Service Not Found</h1> Not sure why I am getting this now. My url is valid and api key is active. Anybody have any clue what is causing this? Using the rotten tomatoes api btw.

Answer (score 0):

try doing this instead :

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
```

Comment: This needs more explanation

Answer (score 0):

You can use `org.json.JSONObject` for parsing JSON into usable Java Object.